# Entity frame work calling to function changing id to name

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The DriverId which will be received from this code will be a number.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderDataRepository rep = new OrderDataRepository();

    var results = rep.GetAllOrderData().
                  GroupBy(o => o.DRIVER_ID).
                  Select(g =>
                            new
                            {
                                DriverId = g.Key,
                                OrderCount = g.Count(),
                                OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 
                                                  g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                            }).ToList();

    DataViewer.DataSource = results;
    DataViewer.DataBind();
}
```

I need to change this DriverId number to a name - so I need to call another function called `get` and to receive a name.

```
public User Get(long userId)
{
    return GetQuery().Single(x => x.Id == userId);
}
```

public user get calling an entity "user" which has "id" which is the driverid and "name". I need the name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var results = rep.GetAllOrderData().
              GroupBy(o => o.DRIVER_ID).
              Select(g =>
                        new
                        {
                            DriverId = g.Key,
                            Name = g.Select(d => d.DRIVER_NAME).FirstOrDefault(),
                            OrderCount = g.Count(),
                            OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 
                                              g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: what is ).FirstOrDefault()? how to use it?  what about **public User Get(long userId)
        {
            return GetQuery().Single(x => x.Id == userId);
        }**

Comment: @user1021182: `FirstOrDefault` is a standard LINQ method. Google it. As for the method you mention, I don't understand what you're asking about it. If you just want the driver's name off of the result, just append `.DRIVER_NAME` after the call to `.Single(...)`. But that extra round-trip to the database is expensive and unnecessary if you can just pull it in as part of the original query.

Comment: I ADDED AN IMAGE TO THE QUESTION - GetAllOrderData connected to an entity that has no "name"...it has only "driverid" therefor i pasted the get function wich is a repository connected to the entity called user and has "id" wich is the driverid.

Comment: @user1021182: Change `d.DRIVER_NAME` in my example to `d.User.RECEIVE_NAME`.

Comment: why?? the recieve name is another name which we dont need...we need the name from the user entity and your example is on the wrong entity we need to call another function wich i already pasted..i dont know how. help pls

Comment: @user1021182: Sorry, I meant `d.User.Name`.